# Why it still can write and read cookie after i disable cookie in IE option?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

WebForm1.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgse)
{
 Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("Name3", "YES..."));
}
```

WebForm2.aspx

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgse)
{
 Response.Write("Your name: " + Request.Cookies["Name3"].Value);
}
```

i have change the IE option to make it block all cookie, but why WebForm2.aspx still can output "YES..."??   i suppose, since i disable all cookie in IE options, should not be able to write and read cookie.

if you have time, can take a quick try.

Comment: When you block cookies in IE, does it keep the *already existing* cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing existing cache data by pressing `Control + D` and then choosing cookies and click on ok.